# Laptop LCD Screen Turned SkyBlue

Tags: laptop, display, troubleshooting, dell-inspiron, lcd

I have been facing issues with my LCD screen of laptop(Dell Inspiron- 3521) as shown in the image.
My screen turn sky blue color automatically. When I move the LCD it becomes OK. 
This happens every 30 min frequency. I ran quick diagnostics but could not find any issues.Some one suggested me that wiring of LCD from the main port might be loose.

One important point is that If I take screenshot, I don't get the sky blue color screen image, I get normal image, so had to take the image by mobile phone.

[image: Laptop Screen Turned Skyblue]

Comment: Your question holds the answer.  It is **obviously** a hardware issue which could be as simple as a loose connection which you should check.  If that doesn't solve it, the screen could be dying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a wire loose. Your colleague is correct, as is Julie Pelletier.

As for the screen shot: Yes, you would not expect a screen shot to display a problem of this nature. Screenshots are files saving the output directly from the display manager before it is sent to the graphics card then onto the screen, which is why it never showed up. It is just one of the factors confirming the problem is hardware from somewhere between the graphics card output to the LCD itself.